# Cannot get HTML table to display data from API

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I followed a tutorial that fetches JSON data from an API and renders this into a table, but when I press the 'Create table' button the table doesn't show up. The 'Create JSON Data' button however is functional and creates dummy data as a test to show in the table, the 'Create Table' button is also working but just doesn't show the table.

Could it be document.GetElementById, var tbl = js.CreateTable, or var tbl = js.CreateTable causing the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>JSON to Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.apidelv.com/libs/awesome-functions/awesome-functions.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chance/1.0.6/chance.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
    <div id="jsonData">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary CreateJSON">Create JSON Array</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary CreateMyTable">Create Table</button>
</div>
</body>

<script>


    $(document).ready(function($)
    {
        function CreateJSONArray()
        {
        var total_rows = 10;

        console.time('create_json_array')
        var arr = []
        for (var i = 0; i < total_rows; i++)
        {
            arr.push({
                "id": i +1,
                "first_name": chance.first(),
                "email": chance.email({domain: 'gmail.com'}),
                "ip_address": chance.ip(),
            })
        };
        console.timeEnd('create_json_array')
        return arr;
        document.getElementById(CreateJSONArray)
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.CreateJSON', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = CreateJSONArray();
        console.log(data);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.CreateMyTable', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = CreateJSONArray();
        //var tbl = js.CreateTable(data);
        var tbl = js.CreateTable(data,['Line Num','First Name','User Emails','IP Address']);

        $('.MyTable').html(tbl);
    });

});
</script>

</head>


</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the table: `<table class="MyTable"></table>` (which is why `$('.MyTable')` comes up blank)

Comment: Thank you so much, I placed that in the body tag and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `table` tag in your `body`, so something like:

```
<table class="MyTable"></table>
```

Don't forget to use the same class as you specify in you js, in this case `MyTable` since `$('.MyTable').html(tbl)`.